# SQL convert column names to row values

Tags: sql, arrays, split, unpivot

I have a table organized as follows:

```
Account Location Measure1 Measure2 Measure3
-------------------------------------------
123a     A       100       20%      5
234b     A        75       80%      8
```

I want to create records as follows:

```
Account Location Measure    Value
-----------------------------------
123a     A       Measure1    100
123a     A       Measure2    20%
123a     A       Measure3    5
234b     A       Measure1    75
234b     A       Measure2    80%
234b     A       Measure3    8
```

Because my measure names are the column headings and not column values under a heading called "Measure" I cannot pivot the data on the measure name.

I know how to query what the column names are by querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. But I'm not sure how to proceed from there. I don't want to do a Union because there are about 100+ measure columns and the table is large.

The only assistance I have been able to find on the web refers to splitting values in a single column (e.g. semi-colon delimited strings) into multiple records. UNPIVOT doesn't work because again the measure name is not a value in a column, it is a column heading.

I would appreciate any assistance you can give me

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, consider using a stored procedure to build your columns list from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. I believe there are lots of tips for this if you search for dynamic queries t-sql. Also, if the table design is static, consider using something like Excel to build your query once and save it off somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

A simple method that works in most databases uses `union all`:

```
select account, location, 'Measure1', Measure1
from t
union all
select account, location, 'Measure2', Measure2
from t
union all
select account, location, 'Measure3', Measure3
from t;
```

In databases that support lateral joins, there is more convenient syntax, such as:

```
select t.account, t.location, v.measure, v.value
from t cross join lateral  -- or maybe cross apply
     (values ('Measure1', t.Measure1), ('Measure2', t.Measure2), ('Measure3', t.Measure3)
     ) v(measure, value);
```